# Preventing removal of linebreaks

Tags: python

I have a function that replaces offensive words with a star, but in running text through this, it strips out linebreaks. Any thoughts on how to prevent this?

```
def replace_words(text, exclude_list):
    words = text.split()
    for i in range(len(words)):
        if words[i].lower() in exclude_list:
            
            words[i] = "*"
    return ' '.join(words)
```

Comment: Perhaps you can split by `\n` first to get all lines in text. And then `.split()` to separate word in each line.

Comment: Is text a single line or multiple lines?

Comment: @Carl_M would they notice that line breaks are stripped if it were a single line?

Comment: "Would they notice that line breaks are stripped if it were a single line?" Yes, depending on the code which calls the function and what is done with the return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `.split()` with no argument on the entire input string, it removes line breaks and you lose the information where you have to put them in the result string.

You could first split the input into lines and then process each line separately in the same way as you now process the whole input.

Comment: [**`str.splitlines`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines)

Answer (score 1):

credit to mkrieger1

```
def replace_words(text, exclude_list):

    paragraphs = text.split('\n')

    new_paragraph = ""

    for p in paragraphs:

        words = p.split()
        for i in range(len(words)):
            if words[i].lower() in exclude_list:
                

                words[i] = "*"
        new_p = ' '.join(words)

        new_paragraph = new_paragraph + "\n" + new_p #add line break

    return new_paragraph
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\n` to create a new line or `.split()`